# Why does my html file not show up in Chrome?

Tags: html

So I started learning HTML today and the first file I coded does not come up in Chrome after being formatted. This is what the code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>Nikolay's Website</title>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

And after I tried opening the file, which is of type "Chrome HTML Document" btw (thought it might help as info), it shows a blank page with no heading. Even if I remove the code and type "Hello World" it would still show a blank page in my browser.

Comment: When asking questions, make sure your code etc. is properly formatted -- now most of the html wasn't visible and people probably wouldn't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried to identify and then fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

HTML page should have the following default structure. Please refer this link https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Nikolay's Website</title>
</head>
<body>
 Hello World
</body>
</html>
```